# Digital Ocean Spaces - Uploading and generating quick share URL

Tags: digital-ocean, boto3

Below code snippet might help for uploading a file and generating quick share URL similar to s3 expiring URL.

```
#create boto client
client = session.client('s3',
                            region_name='nyc3',
                            endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                            aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxx',
                            aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                            config=Config(signature_version='s3'))

#upload file to spaces
client.upload_file('~/test.png', 'bucket_name', 'test.png')

#download file
url = client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object', 
                                        Params={'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
                                                'Key': 'test.png'},
                                    ExpiresIn=300)
```